# Facebook comment box shows page url in different way

Tags: html, asp.net, facebook

I have put facebook's comment box in my own web page. Anyone who wants to comment or like the page can use it. But when sharing link in the facebook page after commenting it shows link in different way:

**Example**

my page url is

```
http://www.mypage.com/tr/~/tr/Detail/blog/76.md
```

which is rewritten using URL Rewrite rule. But after sharing the link over Facebook it looks as the following:

```
http://www.mypage.com/tr/~/tr/Detail/blog/76.md?lang=tr%2F~%2Ftr&read=blog&content=76
```

A part of my URL Rewrite rule is in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<urlrewritingnet 
    rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" 
    contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" 
    defaultPage="Default.aspx" 
    xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">

    <rewrites>
        <add 
            name="DetailPage" 
            virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/Detail/(.*)/(.*).md"  
            rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
            destinationUrl="~/Detail.aspx?lang=$1&amp;read=$2&amp;content=$3" 
            ignoreCase=" true"
        />

        <!-- ... -->

    </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

How can I shoot this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I understand now what is happenning.

I was using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

to get the page address. Instead I write

```
"http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```

then the problem flies away.